# For $A$, $B$, $C$, $X$ on a circle of radius $r$, is it possible to find the area of $\triangle ABC$ given distances $AX$, $BX$, $CX$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, area

> Construct a circle with some radius, $r$, and centre, $O$, and pick any four points on its circumference: $A$, $B$, $C$, and $X$. Is it possible to find the area of $\triangle ABC$, given $AX$, $BX$, $CX$, and $r$? If so, what is the formula to do so? If not, why not?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3469151/edit) to add details.

Comment: The distance $AX,BX,CX$ alone is not enough to pin down the triangle. In general, there are more than one triangle with given distances. Consider the case $r = 1$, $AX = 2$, $BX = 1$ and $CX = 0.999$, it is clear there are two inequivalent  configuration for $ABC$, one is close to a right angled triangle while the other one close to degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

No. The reason is that there are several triangles, all with the same $AX$, $BX$, $CX$, with different areas. Draw a circle of radius $r$. For simplicity, choose $X$ at the bottom. Where are all the points at distance $AX$ from $X$?

Comment: Yes. In fact even if we assume the order of points round the circle is known, there are still two possible triangles with different areas, except in special cases.

Answer (score 1):

Given the radius $r$ and the lengths XA, XB and XC, the triangle ABC can have four configurations, as shown in the diagram. (XA $\le$ XB $\le$ XC without loss of generality.)

[image]

The area of the triangle is given by

$$K = 2r^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the three angles of the triangle, to be expressed in terms of the given lengths. Let $\theta_a$,  $\theta_b$ and  $\theta_c$ be the angles formed between the diameter XY and XA, XB and XC, respectively,

$$\theta_a=\cos^{-1}\frac {XA}{2r},\>\>\>\>\>
\theta_b=\cos^{-1}\frac {XB}{2r},\>\>\>\>\>
\theta_c=\cos^{-1}\frac {XC}{2r}$$

Then, for case 1, we have $\alpha = \theta_b-\theta_c$, $\beta= \pi - (\theta_a-\theta_c)$ and $\gamma= \theta_a-\theta_b$. Thus, its area is,

$$K_1 = 2r^2\sin(\theta_b-\theta_c)\sin(\theta_a-\theta_c)\sin( \theta_a-\theta_b)$$

Similarly,

$$K_2 = 2r^2\sin(\theta_b+\theta_c)\sin(\theta_a+\theta_c)\sin( \theta_a-\theta_b)$$
$$K_3 = 2r^2\sin(\theta_b+\theta_c)\sin(\theta_a-\theta_c)\sin( \theta_a+\theta_b)$$
$$K_4 = 2r^2\sin(\theta_b-\theta_c)\sin(\theta_a+\theta_c)\sin( \theta_a+\theta_b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let XA = a, XB = b, XC = c.

[image]

$F(b, r) \rightarrow \angle yellow$ ;when F is the cosine function.

$F(a, r) \rightarrow \angle (red + yellow)$. Then, $\angle red$ is known.

$F(c, r) \rightarrow \angle green$.

$G(a, b, \angle red) \rightarrow [\triangle XAB]$; where G is the area function.

Similarly, $G(b, c, \angle (green + yellow)) \rightarrow [\triangle XBC]$.

Therefore, [quad ABCD] is known.

$G(a, c, \angle (red + yellow + green)) \rightarrow [\triangle XAC]$.

$[\triangle ABC]$ is found by subtraction.

---

In general, If we let $\angle red = \angle 1$, $\angle yellow = \angle 2$, $\angle green = \angle 3$,

then $[\triangle ABC] = \dfrac {ab \sin \angle 1}{2} + \dfrac {bc \sin \angle (2 + 3)}{2} -  \dfrac {ca \sin \angle (1 + 2 + 3)}{2} $

A slight variation will occur depending how XB is inclined.